# how to filter groups that have products linked to them by a foreign key django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i am trying to filter groups that match with products that share a foreign key in between, foreign key is being set from the Product. i have done it correctly but i believe that there is an easier and a better way to do it.

## views.py

```
def shop(request, shop_url):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    groups = None
    for product in products:
        groups = Group.objects.filter(id=product.item_group.id)
    context = {
        'products' : products,
        'groups' : groups,
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/shop.html', context)
```

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: What is the point of your querysets and for loop. It will always return all objects from both models?

Comment: nope, the for loop is used to check for each product if the item_group inside it contains any group by using the filter method. if it meets it then it will be viewed in the template. Products will be viewed at all times groups will only be viewed when it meets the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you filtered your products before, because if you use all products, it means that retrieve all groups.

You can use following query:

```
group_ids = Product.objects.filter(...).values_list('item_group_id',flat=True)
groups = Group.objects.filter(id__in=group_ids)
```

Comment: Thank you, i am kinda of a beginner in Django so i would like to know the difference in running speeds while running both qeury's. will using this piece of code give faster results ?

Comment: Because, there is two database hit in this method. But if you create a loop for products and use query for each this product inside this loop, you have n database hits. n means that, product count. So we assume you have 100 product, you will hit 100 times to get groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your querysets will always return all objects from both models. You can simply change your code to,

```
def shop(request, shop_url):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    groups = Group.objects.all()

    context = {
        'products' : products,
        'groups' : groups,
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/shop.html', context)
```

Comment: well actually the products are filtered before using them.

Comment: you should've mentioned.

Comment: yeah, my mistake.